# How gradle interprets a command run at parent level

Tags: gradle

Let's say there are 3 sub projects: sub1, sub2, and sub3. They all have task `uploadArchives`. If we run `gradle uploadArchives`, how it is cascaded to sub projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your project layout as bellow

```
gradle-tasks
|- sub1
|- sub2
|- sub3
```

`settings.gradle` as below:

```
include 'sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3'
rootProject.name = 'gradle-tasks'
```

And your `build.gradle` is like this:

```
allprojects {
    task uploadArchives {
        doLast { task ->
            println "I'm $task.project.name"
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you execute `./gradlew uploadArchives` in root, you will have

```
$ ./gradlew uploadArchives

> Task :uploadArchives 
I'm gradle-tasks

> Task :sub1:uploadArchives 
I'm sub1

> Task :sub2:uploadArchives 
I'm sub2

> Task :sub3:uploadArchives 
I'm sub3
```

Ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html